# How to set a max width on a subview of HSplitView

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm having some trouble with `HSplitView` on macOS, and I'm not sure if it's a bug or something I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to create an app with a `[Sidebar | Main Content | Inspector]` layout. This is similar to the SF Symbols app, where you can view more information about a selected icon.

The approach I've taken is to have the `Main Content` and `Inspector` views be in an `HSplitView`. Having three views in a `NavigationView` only seems to use the Mail pattern of `[List | List | Detail]`, which is not the layout I'm looking for.

The problem I'm seeing is that when I set a `maxWidth` on the `Inspector` view and drag the divider to the left, the `Main Content` view resizes to be smaller than the available space. The parent `HSplitView` doesn't resize, so I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong modifiers or using them in the wrong places.

I've setup a [basic test case on github](https://github.com/mike-engel/split-view-test). If y'all could offer and help or guidance, that would be amazing.

**Observed behaviour**
[image: GIF of the observed behaviour]

**Expected behaviour**
[image: GIF of the expected behaviour]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct A: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Pane A")
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth: 200,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: .leading
        )
        .background(Color.red)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .layoutPriority(1)
    }
}

struct B: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Pane B")
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth: 200,
            idealWidth: 250,
            maxWidth: 300,
            maxHeight: .infinity
        )
        .background(Color.purple)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HSplitView {
            A()
            B()
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth: 0,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity
        )
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}e
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem for several days, and I solved it in a flash.

Need to drag View

```swift
HSplitView {
    View1()
    View2()
}
```

Intuitively, we will set the maximum width of View1, **but when SwiftUI drags, View1 exceeds the maximum width, it will display an inexplicable error**

```swift
HSplitView {
    View1()
        .frame(maxWidth: 300)
    View2()
}
```

**Solutions**
**Set the minimum width of View2**, and let View automatically fill all spaces. There will be no drag problem

```swift
HSplitView {
    View1()
    View2()
        .frame(minWidth: 500)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WU_C! This won't work for my case, however. I have two views in a window. The window can be resized. `View1` should only be able to be 300 pixels wide.

In order for your solution to work, I would need to know the size of the window when setting the `minWidth` of `View2`. It's probably possible with `GeometryReader`, but I shouldn't need to do that.

If the window is 1000 pixels wide, `View2` would need `minWidth: 700`. But if the window was resized by the user to be 1500 pixels wide, `View2` would then need to have `minWidth: 1200`.

Comment: Sorry, really can't solve your problem. It seems that I can only wait for the official to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Embedding one split view inside other may work.
Some problems arise if using GeometryReader.

```
HSplitView
{
    View1()
    HSplitView
    {
    View2()
    View3()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).